# Button doesn't work in Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new in java programming, I follow some books about JAVA. I use eclipse.

I'm dealing with an easy program but the button's function doesn't work well, this is my code

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    } 

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Recipe.class));
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Recipe.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class Recipe extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipe);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.helloandroidword.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.helloandroidword.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecipe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.helloandroidword"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.helloandroidword.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Recipe"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thanks

Comment: please show your error log.

Comment: You have given too much information still your question is unclear. Please specify your issue with required information only.

Comment: Not related, but since you are just starting Android, switch to Android Studio.

Comment: I am not an Android developer but your `onclick` function call `startActivity` function in which you are doing nothing.

Comment: so i try with studio but have some problem with emulator i use debian 32bit with eclipse ,where i can take the error log on emulator ,lawstud?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote your own `findViewById(int btnrecipe)` which always return null:

```
private Button findViewById(int btnrecipe) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

You should call findViewById from the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Intent` for going on next screen(Activity).

Do one thing in your onClickListener add below code.

`Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this, recipe.class);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: i try to put this code on main.java after the call onClickListener but i have error i can put main.this not activity because with activity i have error,thak a lot

Comment: I could not understand your point but anyway if your issue is solved. I am happy for you, Keep coding Keep learning...pleasure helping & solving issue.

Answer (score 1):

In activity class you didt `extend` it with `Activity`

`public class activity`

change to

`public class activity extends Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Renaming `activity` to `MyActivity` to keep upto standard naming conventions.

Your `activity` class should look like this,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecipe);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, recipe.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Also in `recipe` class change,

`public class recipe extends MainActivity`

to,

`public class recipe extends Activity`

In your manifest change,

`<activity-alias android:name=".recipe"/>`

to,

`<activity android:name=".recipe"/>`

Comment: i upload the app on the emulator all work well but the button not work...and more not have error on eclipse...

Comment: button is on Main class metod onCreate

Comment: @a_ton See edit. Also update the code in the question along with layout.

Comment: the error when start the app is : gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags :246 x 410 ,usage 333 GraficBufferAlloc::createGraficBuffer(w=246, h410) failed  (Invalid argument), handle =0x0...[ScreenshotClient] dequeBuffer : Surface Composer::createGraficBuffer failed..

Comment: so i take your edit... but i think there is one Main.this wrong...on line ....getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Main.this ,Recipe.class)...this main because the class Main is delete on yuor edit...thanks

Comment: The button is in your fragment.

Comment: give me tihs error : multiple markers on his line : -No eclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible in scope . -Main cannot be resolved to type.thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for the contrib  particulary thanks at  K Neeraj Lal ...follow the code.
MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }




/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Recipe.class));


            }


        });
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Recipe.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;

public class Recipe extends ActionBarActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.androidbootcamp.healthyrecipes.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="clic"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

recipe.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="pomodori"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="acqua"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="sale"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="pepe"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```